# How can these code blocks produce seemingly identical results that function differently later?

Tags: objective-c

Can anyone tell me the functional difference between this code...

> for (int i = 0; i < productsJSON.count; i++)
>      {
>          prod = [[Product alloc] init];
>
> ```
>    prod.ItemID = [[productsJSON valueForKey:@"ItemID"] objectAtIndex:i];
>    prod.Name = [[productsJSON valueForKey:@"Name"] objectAtIndex:i];
>
>    [self.products addObject:prod];
> ```
>
> }
>      [super viewDidLoad];

... and this code...

> prod = [[Product alloc] init];
>      prod.ItemID = @"SB4UL";
>      prod.Name = @"#4 Split Bolt- UL Approved";
>      [self.products addObject:prod];
>
> prod = [[Product alloc] init];
>      prod.ItemID = @"PVSC07GGUL";
>      prod.Name = @"I Beam Grounding Clamp, UL";
>      [self.products addObject:prod];
>
> [super viewDidLoad];

... when prod.ItemID and prod.Name are NSString properties, and the values assigned in the "for" loop have -- after exiting the loop -- been visually confirmed to be the same as values assigned by the other block of code?

For all I can tell, both behave exactly the same until the moment I actually try to put the results to practical use in my app. The code appears in the viewDidLoad method of a UITableViewController. It gets passed to the cellForRowAtIndexPath method, where I can confirm that the values arrive intact. Then we step straight into the code block...

> UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ProductCell"];
>      Product *product = [self.products objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
>      cell.textLabel.text = product.Name;

If I've commented out the first block and run the second, the view displays flawlessly.

If I've commented out the second block and run the first, the program dies every time at "cell.textLabel.text = product.Name", and it displays a seemingly random error message (e.g.: "Thread 1: EXEC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_1386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)" or "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT" or "Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, adress=0xf069996f").

Comment: Which OS version and how is `ItemID` and `Name` declared. If they are `unsafe_unretained` references they are being deallocated too soon and that may be why it is crashing. The reason the second example works because you are using literals which do not get deallocated.

Comment: Also did you verify that `[[productsJSON valueForKey:@"ItemID"] objectAtIndex:i]` is returning a string? Is `ItemID` an array of strings in the JSON?

Comment: You're right. I was tricked by the fact that the Array is retained, but the properties on the individual Product objects weren't being protected by the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Joe was right -- I just had to dig deeper to find it. The array is persistent, but the properties on the Product class were not.

The productsJSON code is a variable specific to viewDidLoad. It died between methods, and the reference in the Product objects went bad.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your code, for example :

```
prod.ItemID = [[productsJSON valueForKey:@"ItemID"] objectAtIndex:i];
```

I suppose that productsJSON is a dictionary, then :

```
[productsJSON valueForKey:@"ItemID"]; // <-- is this an array?
```

first doubt: it seems to me that this will return you a string? am I wrong? if I'm wrong

I'm just guessing now but I think that your code should be something like this :

```
for (int i = 0; i < productsJSON.count; i++) { 
  prod = [[Product alloc] init];
  prod.ItemID = [[productsJSON objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"ItemID"];
  prod.Name   = [[productsJSON objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"Name"];
  [self.products addObject:prod];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It came out to the same result, but it was worth a shot.

Comment: productJSON is an NSMutableArray, ultimately build from the JSON code retrieved via a web service. If it's any help, here's the code that transforms it from that:

Comment: >> NSDictionary *jsonOutput = [login getJSONObject:@"Products": arguments];
>> NSMutableArray *productsJSON = [jsonOutput valueForKey:@"Products"];

Comment: Sorry for the spam, but I'm still figuring out the mechanical differences between posting a question and posting a comment. And, yes, the valueForKey:@"ItemID" does return a string.

Comment: what if you do an NSLog(@"%@",product.Name); in cellForRow?

Comment: The idea was useful. I'm green enough with objective-c that I was having to force more awkward code than NSLog to display my debugging info. But it sadly corroborates exactly what I was already seeing: the values assigned by my "for" loop from web-service data vanish on their way to being used in cellForRowAtIndexPath, those values made up and assigned directly in the code don't. This holds true even if I assign all 4 records to a single array and deliver them together as a unit, the values are identical, and I filter loop-data through an NSString variable before assigning. 2 stay, 2 vanish.